# How do I change the directory where pip installs packages?

Tags: python, pip, site-packages

I have a ploblem where pip installs packages in the wrong directory: `C:\Users\mikke\AppData\Roaming\python\python311\sitepackages`, but my python is installed in `C:\Program Files\Python311`. I'm pretty new to python and use pycharm as my IDE, the problem i have is that pycharm doesn't recognize any of the packages I install and I'm pretty sure it's because they are installed in the wrong directory.

First I tried to go on the internet to find answers on how to do this, but I couldn't find anthing. Then I tried to go into my system variables and found out I had two different varibles to python script and one of the variables had the path: `C:\Users\mikke\AppData\Roaming\python\python311\scripts`, so i deleted the one with the path i didn't want my packages to go to, but it didn't work.
Then I tried to uninstall pip, with the command: `python -m pip uninstall pip`, it deleted the pip exe's in the scipts folder, but when i tried to install the packages again it still installed to the wrong directory.

Comment: Did you follow the PyCharm [Install, uninstall, and upgrade packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) instructions?

Comment: @jarmod no i hadn't thanks a lot, this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm typically uses one of a selection of virtual environments, and this is selectable by project.

For more information on how to locate the virtual environment for a given project and how to  Install, uninstall, and upgrade packages, see the PyCharm documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#upgrade-packages).

Essentially the process is:

1. open project settings
2. choose Python Interpreter
3. click + icon to add a new Python package